# Insert records from a View into a Table via a Trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, triggers

I would like to insert values from a view into a table, via a trigger set against the view.

I'm trying to add records to the table where the view has "newer" updated records. I need to use the view because of the way  the data is transformed. To trigger I would want to create an `IF` for when  `table.column1 <> view.column1 and table.column2 <> view.column2` for example. This would then add that "newer" record

What is the best way to achieve this ?

I am using PostgreSQL. I tried this but it won't work because it's a view

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION function_name
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS
$$

BEGIN

    IF (NEW.VIEW_Colummn1 = OLD.Table_column1 AND NEW.VIEW_Colummn2 = OLD.Table_column2 AND NEW.VIEW_Column3 <> OLD.Table_column3)
        OR
        (NEW.VIEW_Colummn1 = OLD.Table_column1 AND NEW.VIEW_Colummn2 = OLD.Table_column2)

        THEN INSERT INTO "Table"(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5)

                VALUES(NEW.VIEW_Colummn1,NEW.VIEW_Colummn2,NEW.VIEW_Colummn3,NEW.VIEW_Colummn4, NEW.VIEW_Colummn5);
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;

END;
$$
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name

  After UPDATE
  ON VIEW
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_name();
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS. [please add your attempted code]

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community is here to help you with issues, however it **is not a code writing service**. Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the review help section [ask]. Specifically provide sample data and definitions ( table  ddl and view query) and the expected results of that data.  Also describe what you are trying to do,not how.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is not clear. Views don't hold data. Perhaps you should describe the underlying problem you are trying to solve with that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - thanks. So the view provides live data in a specific transformed manner which I need. What alternative could store this transformed data that I could place a trigger on ? Basically when the live data changes I want to trigger an insert row to a table to track some audit requirements. 

Placing triggers based on the underlying tables on the view is possible but there are many many tables referenced so there would be many triggers so I'm trying to avoid that  Hope this expands the problem a bit

Comment: I see. I am afraid that you will have to have triggers on the underlying tables.